# I cannot install Matlab 2014a on OS X Yosemite 10.10 public beta

Tags: macos, matlab

When I install Matlab 2014a on OS X Yosemite 10.10 public beta, it shows Matlab logo and then it says: “Install MATLAB quit unexpectedly.”

1.I install JDK/JRE before I try to install Matlab, but it still not works.

2.I changed ProductVersion in SystemVersion.plist to 10.90 or 10.9 according to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoQnzIyOkB0 before I install Matlab, but it also still not works.

What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: If your MATLAB license is through your university, company, etc, best talk to your local IT support.  If not, contact Mathworks directly, they're more likely to be able to give you a clear answer. (It may also depend on MATLAB version).

Comment: In addition to the video that you have shown, there is an additional patch you can do if you're running Yosemite Public Beta v2.  Check out  this MathWorks thread here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/336387 .  Also, check this thread on Super User: http://superuser.com/questions/764282/matlab-crashes-on-launch-os-x-yosemite

Comment: Thank you. But now my problem is that I cannot install it rather than that cannot run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those having the same problem with 10.10 beta 5 & Matlab R2014a.

You can fix the problem with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Fool the system into believing you are using Mavericks by replacing
# the version 10.10 to 10.90, you obviously need sudo to do this. 
sudo vim -c "%s/10.10/10.90/ge" -c 'w!' -c 'q' "/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"

# Launch Matlab via the executable
/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/matlab

# Revert the version change in the SystemVersion.plist file
sudo vim -c "%s/10.90/10.10/ge" -c 'w!' -c 'q' "/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"
```

Then all there is to do put this script in the PATH somewhere and call it from the command line to use Matlab in 10.10 :)

Comment: Hey my new solution is here. It works perfect. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/143601-i-cannot-install-matlab-2014a-on-os-x-yosemite-10-10-public-beta