# Using MATLAB with OS X 10

Tags: matlab, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded to OS X 10 Yosemite but cannot launch MATLAB.

I've tried opening it through terminal with:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/matlab
```

However this doesn't work either. Any ideas?

**EDIT: I have found an answer to my question!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT 11/29/2021:

DtecNet, Inc. filed a DMCA complaint on this for some reason. Guess they can't have anybody using MATLAB on Yosemite.

---

There is a patch out for MATLAB R2014a that I got from a classmate.

The patch allows you to be able to run MATLAB without changing any settings on your computer, just in the MATLAB app itself.

You can download a copy of the patch [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?iwjtnzc99mkpi10).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MATLAB R2014a is not compatible with Yosemite, see http://www.mathworks.it/support/sysreq/roadmap.html. You should upgrade to R2014b.

There seems to be a workaround at [I cannot install Matlab 2014a on OS X Yosemite 10.10 public beta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24994553/3676517).